# What is an extension language? Example: python can be used as an extension language

Tags: python

How is it different from scripting languages?

Answer (score 6):

An extension language is just what it sounds like. A language that is used to extend other applications. For example, when you write a macro in Excel using Visual Basic, that's using VB as a extension language. When you write a plugin for your browser with Javascript, that is using JS as an extension language.

Extension Language is a language used to write extensions.

Answer (score 2):

This means you can "easily" connect Python with other languages.

One example would be to have a main program in C, and use external Python scripts inside.

To illustrate, imagine a program in C that computes a labyrinth, and a Python script that gives a strategy to walk through the labyrinth. A user could define his/her own strategies in Python instead of diving in the C code.
The user would execute the C code, giving the Python script filepath as an argument, and the C code would execute the Python code as the strategy to use.

One nice property is that you can change the Python script and never recompile the C code.